# How to get Ansible on Fedora 30 to see modules

Tags: python, path, ansible, fedora

I installed Ansible 2.8.2 using `dnf` on Fedora 30. I have an Ansible plug-in that requires a library. Using `pip3 install` I installed the required library.

When I run `ansible-playbook` directly, I see a `ModuleNotFoundError` for that module.

But if I run `python3 /usr/bin/ansible-playbook`, the module is found.

How can I get Ansible as installed by `dnf` to see this library?

**Edit:** further info: as installed from `dnf`, the main Ansible script has a shebang for `/usr/bin/python3 -s`. If I remove the `-s`, this problem is solved.

1. What's the benefit that the repo maintainers were seeking in adding this `-s` flag?
2. Is there a case to be made for asking the repo maintainers to omit the flag?
3. How can I get `pip3` to install the library I need into a directory that will be seen when the `-s` flag is in effect?

**Edit:** Here's the output of `ansible --version`, and thanks for asking.

```
ansible 2.8.2
  config file = /home/jdashton/proj/ansible-ccharacter/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/jdashton/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 16:32:37) [GCC 9.1.1 20190503 (Red Hat 9.1.1-1)]
```

This is different from the suggested duplicate question because that question describes a "remote" task being run on localhost, in which case Ansible uses the default "remote" python interpreter. In this question, the library is being called from a local plugin, under Ansible's own python process. The `-s` flag in the shebang line at the top of the `/usr/bin/ansible` script is preventing Ansible from seeing some local libraries.

**Edit:** Following the suggestion from @zigarn I tried removing the library and reinstalling it as `root`. This resulted in the library being reinstalled into the same directory `/usr/local/lib/...` as before. Is there a way to get `pip3` to install into the system library?

Here are the commands I attempted:

```
# pip3 uninstall tenacity
Uninstalling tenacity-5.0.4:
  Would remove:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity-5.0.4.dist-info/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled tenacity-5.0.4
# pip3 install tenacity
Collecting tenacity
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/93/dfcf5b1b46ab29196274b78dcba69fab5e54b6dc303a7eed90a79194d277/tenacity-5.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tenacity) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: tenacity
Successfully installed tenacity-5.0.4
# pip show tenacity
Name: tenacity
Version: 5.0.4
Summary: Retry code until it succeeeds
Home-page: https://github.com/jd/tenacity
Author: Julien Danjou
Author-email: julien@danjou.info
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: six
Required-by:
```

Also, for clarity, here is the source for the Ansible installation:

```
# dnf list ansible
Last metadata expiration check: 0:09:48 ago on Mon 12 Aug 2019 11:12:58 AM EDT.
Installed Packages
ansible.noarch                                               2.8.2-1.fc30                                               @updates
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `ansible --version`?

Comment: @MattP, output added in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible doesn't see an installed Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971865/ansible-doesnt-see-an-installed-python-module)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation `-s` option of python is "[Don’t add the user site-packages directory to sys.path.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-s)"

So I would guess that you did `pip3 install` as your user instead as `root`, so the library was installed at your user side instead of system wide.

Try to reinstall the library with `pip3` as `root` and it should be ok.

Comment: I tried this with hope, but hope was dashed. I have edited my original question to show this attempt. But thank you!