# Ansible unable to find `zabbix-api`

Tags: python, ansible, zabbix

### Problem

In this scenario Ansible is unable to locate Zabbix API. Ansible spits out the following error when running a playbook that calls the `zabbix-api` module:

```sh
msg: 'Missing required zabbix-api module (check docs or install with: pip install zabbix-api)'
```

### Environment

The control node, running Ubuntu 18.04, contains multiple python interpreters (2.7/3.6/3.7). Zabbix API has been installed on the control node using pip (`pip install zabbix-api`) for python2.7 in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. This can be observed after running the following:

```sh
import imp
imp.find_module('zabbix_api')
```

which outputs:

```sh
(<open file '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zabbix_api.py', mode 'U' at 0x7f102e990540>, '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zabbix_api.py', ('.py', 'U', 1)
```

### Checks

I have made sure that:

- Ansible loads the correct Python interpreter: `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python`
- PATH contains the path to the interpreter's `site-packages` or `dist-packages`
- the interpreter can load the `zabbix_api` library: `python -c "import zabbix_api"`
- `zabbix_api.py` permissions are correct
- `sys.path` contains the path to `zabbix_api` dir:

```sh
import sys
print '\n'.join(sys.path)
```

Which outputs:

```sh
    /usr/lib/python2.7
    /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
    /home/peter/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

What am I missing here? Are there any other factors to take into account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible doesn't see an installed Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971865/ansible-doesnt-see-an-installed-python-module)

Comment: How does your task look like, does it have `local_action` or another way to run the task from the controller? If not, this would run on the target host instead.

Comment: Richlv & Iain Shelvington, please see my answer below. Your pointers helped me realise that the hosts file was misconfigured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this issue was a misconfiguration of the hosts file: Ansible was targeting the wrong server. After ensuring that the playbook was executed on the localhost the issue was resolved.